# python automatically pass variables to function

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

I have code like this

```
def function3():
    print(text)

def function2():
    text = "Hello"
    function3()

def function1():
    text = "World"
    function3()
```

Like you see i want to automatically pass variable from function2 and function1 to function3. This variable should be visible only on this three functions (so I can't set it global). Also I don't want to pass this variable every time between round brackets, because I will use function3 thousands of times. 
Is there a something like keyword use in php?

```
function3() use (text):
    print(text)
```

Comment: So pass them in normally. "Explicit is better than implicit". I don't understand your reasoning. What is the difference between having `function3()` "thousands of  times" and having `function3(arg)` "thousands of times" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share variable between functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636867/how-to-share-variable-between-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I now what you want to do (don't know php), but is it just something like this?

```
def function3(text):
    print(text)

def function2():
    text = "Hello"
    function3(text)

def function1():
    text = "World"
    function3(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing directly equivalent, you would normally just pass the arguments around.

From what I understand, the `use` keyword in PHP to manually add variables to an anonymous function's closure. In python, function scopes already create closures for you automatically using lexical scoping rules. You can do something like this:

```
def function_maker():
    text = None # need to initialize a variable in the outer function scope
    def function3():
        print(text)

    def function2():
        nonlocal text
        text = "Hello"
        function3()

    def function1():
        nonlocal text
        text = "World"
        function3()

    return function1, function2, function3

function1, function2, function3 = function_maker()
```

But this pattern wouldn't be common in Python, you would just use a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, text): # maybe add a constructor
        self.text = text

    def function3(self):
        print(self.text)

    def function2(self):
        self.text = "Hello"
        self.function3()

    def function1(self):
        self.text = "World"
        self.function3()
```